# I am not able to use mapDispatchToProps in my React + Redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

In my React + Redux application I am trying to use **mapDispatchToProps** utility, But whenever I put this inside `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` it gives me an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function at new ReduxApp (ReduxApp.js:42)`

What could be the issue in this?
PS: below is the file

**ReduxApp.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 import { history } from './_helpers';
 import { alertActions } from './_actions'

 class ReduxApp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      const { dispatch } = this.props;

      dispatch(alertActions.success("hello world"));
  }

  handleChange(){

      this.props.dispatch(alertActions.clear());
  }

  render(){
     const { alert } = this.props;
     return(

      <div>

         <h1>{alert.message}</h1>
         <button onClick={this.handleChange}>clear</button> {/* this is working since this function is declared outside the mapDispatchToProps. */}
         <button onClick={this.props.handleClick}>clear</button>

      </div>

     );

   }

 }

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ 
   alert : state.alert
 });

 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   handleClick: () => dispatch(alertActions.clear())
 });

 const connectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReduxApp); // when I add mapDispatchToProps in the connect(), I get thhe issue.
 export { connectedApp as ReduxApp }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you first need to pass `dispatch` as it is not available when using `mapDispatchToProps` (see this answer by @gaeron Redux's creator: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/255)

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleClick: () => alertActions.clear(dispatch),
  dispatch,
});
```

Update your actionCreator to dispatch the action now that `dispatch`'s reference is available:

```
alert.clear = dispatch => {
  // your logic
  dispatch(ALERT_CLEAR_ACTION) // or whatever you named your action
}
```

And in your component:

```
handleChange = () => this.props.handleClick();
```

Comment: I could solve the issue just by returning `dispatch` along with the `handleClick()` inside the `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: Note that this is answered in the Redux FAQ: [Why don't I have props.dispatch available in my connected component?](https://redux.js.org/faq/reactredux#why-dont-i-have-this-props-dispatch-available-in-my-connected-component).

Comment: @markerikson Thank you, I have posted that as an Answer to the Question.

Answer (score 2):

From React Redux [**Official Documentation**](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes)

**Why don't I have this.props.dispatch available in my connected component?**

The `connect()` function takes two primary arguments, both optional. The first, `mapStateToProps`, is a function you provide to pull data from the store when it changes, and pass those values as props to your component. The second, `mapDispatchToProps`, is a function you provide to make use of the store's dispatch function, usually by creating pre-bound versions of action creators that will automatically dispatch their actions as soon as they are called.

If you do not provide your own `mapDispatchToProps` function when calling `connect()`, React Redux will provide a default version, which simply returns the dispatch function as a prop. That means that if you do provide your own function, `dispatch` is not automatically provided. If you still want it available as a prop, you need to explicitly return it yourself in your `mapDispatchToProps` implementation.

The issue got solved after returning `dispatch` in the `mapDispatchToProps` implementation

```
 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
         handleClick: () => dispatch(alertActions.clear()),
         dispatch, //returning dispatch solves the issue
 });
```

Note: If we use [**PropTypes**](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes) no need to retun `mapDispatchToProps`